# Using VB DLL Visual Studio 2008 Run in Windows 7 ERROR

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7-x64

when i'm using [VB DLL] in VS2008 running in Windows7 32BIT , it works fine,

BUT when i run the [VB DLL] in VS2008 in windows7 64BIT , it give me the following error:

> An error occurred creating the form.
>   See Exception.InnerException for
>   details.  The error is: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Interop.HMS_Server,
>   Version=784.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified.

ANY SUGGESTIONS PLEASE  ABOUT HOW TO RUN THE APPLICATION???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Register it or other OCX and COM DLLs in SysWOW64